# How to copy csv data in PostgreSQL WITHOUT superuser access and cannot use any shell command?

Tags: sql, postgresql, superuser

For some reasons, we have to use commands that are not shell commands (so \copy or psql cannot be used). And if we use normal copy command, the superuser access will prevent it.

I expect it would copy data to the database properly.

Comment: The user does not necessarily need to be  the superuser. From here [COPY](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-copy.html): *. COPY naming a file or command is only allowed to database superusers or users who are granted one of the roles pg_read_server_files, pg_write_server_files, or pg_execute_server_program, since it allows reading or writing any file or running a program that the server has privileges to access.*

Comment: Are you using a client library to access the database? Say like  the Python library `psycopg2` that has [Copy Methods](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/usage.html#using-copy-to-and-copy-from) where you can access local file files without  the Postgres `COPY` restrictions.

Comment: Many programming languages have support for the copy protocol

Comment: Please specify what programming language and development environment you are using. It might also be usefule to be more specific about the "some reasons".

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.